# WordPress: Get posts list of custom post type in an array, and pick random ones

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, random, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type named 'pavideo'. I can get the list of all posts in this custom post type with this code:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'pavideo' ) );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    the_title();
    echo '</a></li>';
endwhile;
?>
```

What I need is to get all this pages in an array, so I can choose 4 random ones and display it on a page. How could I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of getting all the posts, you can modify your query to return only 4 posts with a random order-by clause:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'pavideo', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) );
```

Comment: Ok, that was easier than I thought. Thank you a lot!